# Problems when entering a parenthesis in VSCode or other text editors

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

[parenthesis problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BwMR.png)

hi, As you can see in the image, when I enter the opening parenthesis, it displays an 'é,' and I'm not sure why this happens. This issue occurs not only in VSCode but also on websites like LeetCode or HackerRank. Visual Studio 2022 works correctly. I've tried to search for a solution, but I haven't found one. I hope you can help me

I tried changing the keyboard and language settings, but it didn't work.

Comment: you can use keyboard debugging to see what VSC is doing with a key press

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.